# GeoGebra Simulations -- output to file

Tags: geogebra

Given some composition of objects, I would like to modify some *input parameters* and see how the *output* changes. The relation of input and resulting output parameters shall be written to a file.

**EXAMPLE**: Area of rectangle depending on position of point A.

```
       A *-----------------.
         |                 |
         |                 |
         |                 |
         '-----------------* B
```

Point A is determined by its x and y coordinates. The edges of the rectangle are aligned with the edges of the coordinate system. Together with another point B, A spans the rectangle. The resulting rectangle has an area 'F'. Now, I would like to do something like the following

```
for x in range(0,5)
    for y in range(0,5)
        A = (x,y)
        # Assume GeoGebra does all the adaptations.
        myFile.write(x, y, F.area)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the areas into a sequence:

`Join(Sequence(Sequence({i,j,Polygon(B,(i,y(B)),(i,j),(x(B),j))},i,0,5),j,0,5))`

but there is no way to pro programmatically save it into a file. You can use `CopyFreeObject` to convert it into a free object and copy the new matrix to a text editor of your choosing.

Maybe using GeoGebra's spreadsheet instead of sequence could make the copying easier.